# Wordpress Changes Not Updating

Tags: wordpress

I have been doing some changes to WordPress Pages, It was all fine at the start , Files are being updated successfully. Then i opened private browsing window of Firefox and check the same website then i came to know that half of my work is updated but the new changes are not being showed unless i login to admin panel. Problem here is i can see changes if i am login as admin. If i am not i can't see half of my changes. Remember i don't have any caching plugins installed. I tried almost anything i got on google. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you cant answer don't down vote please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99.99% cache use cntrl + F5 (hard flush) works all the time + check you Cpanel for clear cache maybe the have done it for you without knowing

Comment: it has fixed automatically. today

Comment: Glad To here :)